# Room DB migration SELECT statement causes SQLiteException

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, select, android-room

In the Google Play Developer console logs I'm seeing the following **SQLiteException** error for a small number of users. I've tried to re-create this error on my own devices, but it runs fine without error. It also runs fine for the majority of people who use my app.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run (RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: 
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement (Native Method)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:1463)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare (SQLiteConnection.java:901)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:590)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init> (SQLiteProgram.java:62)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init> (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query (SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.java:2063)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.java:2038)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query (FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:161)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.query (FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:150)
  at com.olivetree.android.tracker.roomdb.db.Migration_2_3.getPersonId (Migration_2_3.java:166)
  at com.olivetree.android.tracker.roomdb.db.Migration_2_3.migrate (Migration_2_3.java:91)
```

This error is triggered by line 166 in my Room DB migration class inside the method getPersonId(). This line of code attempts to get the record of the last personId from the Settings DB table:

```
// Run query on setting DB table
Cursor cursor = db.query("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.DB_TABLE_SETTING + " WHERE type = " + Constants.DB_SETTING_TYPE_LAST_USED_PERSON_ID);
```

Full method for reference:

```
private boolean getPersonId(SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {

        boolean personIdFound = false;

        // Run query on setting DB table. It crashes on this line below:
        Cursor cursor = db.query("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.DB_TABLE_SETTING + " WHERE type = " + Constants.DB_SETTING_TYPE_LAST_USED_PERSON_ID);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            this.mPersonId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("value"));
            personIdFound = true;
        }
        cursor.close();

        return personIdFound;
    }
```

Elsewhere in my Constants class, I define the following:

```
public static final String DB_TABLE_SETTING = "setting";
public static final int DB_SETTING_TYPE_LAST_USED_PERSON_ID = 2;
```

I'm not sure why this error is happening for some users. Is the DB query string badly formed?

Comment: The SQL seems like it should be OK. Is there some scenario where the user might not have a `setting` table, or that table might not have a `type` column?

Comment: @CommonsWare no, the `setting` table with column `type` should be present in Migration_1_2. Plus, I just gave them both a different name (so they are not present) and I get 2 errors clearly indicating that:


`Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: settingabcd` 
`Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: typeabcd`

Comment: The below uses single-quotes (which also works when I run it). Am wondering if this might solve it for some users?


`Cursor cursor = db.query("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.DB_TABLE_SETTING + " WHERE type = '" + Constants.DB_SETTING_TYPE_LAST_USED_PERSON_ID + "'");`

Comment: Similarly, another query() method also works for me:
`String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.DB_TABLE_SETTING + " WHERE type = ?";

Cursor cursor = db.query(query, new String[] {String.valueOf(Constants.DB_SETTING_TYPE_LAST_USED_PERSON_ID)});`